# Form safety wordpress cms

Tags: php, wordpress, security

On my page i want to add a custom text field where clients can enter their own id. The form looks like this:

```
<form method="post">
    Enter your ID here: <input type="text" name="client_id"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I want to keep this form as simple as possible i.e. I don't want to use any unnecessary plugins for just this small thing.

My question : Is adding such a form to your website safe? with safe I mean safe against hacks and such? 
I'm a newbie when it comes to website security so i might as well be talking about something that doesn't make sense right now, so please bear with me.

Comment: You need to sanitize that. I'm sure WP has a standard way to make safe forms, you should learn what it is.  What research have you done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This form is safe, because when it will be submitted, it just call your wordpress-site and hand over the entered data (client_id).

The big question is what do you do after this? Only at this point it can be unsafe.

Comment: What if the user puts javascript in it?

Comment: Basically when the form is submitted i make an api call which retrieves certain data if the entered id matches the  existing id in the api

Comment: I think this is safe if an ID is entered and you only use it to compare to retrive the data for it.

Comment: Thanks for your help